# Duplicate Git Commit?

Tags: git

I'm still pretty new to Git, but I noticed today that a few of my commits are showing up as duplicates with identical SHA-1 and commit messages. What's going on here?

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
739ca79856dc1742890b7790c01c23198c312ae3 cleanup unused js
7ced47ade57a1d677288e7c98a20eaf374fc2efe final (hopefully) ie fix for menu js
66af4165df70640c6f65cf1ba58db48f2d89012d v0.5
f2954f57eaf2b8a9261680d2d34fd4022178b539 Final menu style, added sidebar styling
04432e237098cccd464a17b7a50226d55b7b4c48 ie fix for previous commit
476e33937a9f6bc8383cd04d8cfe967e25090bc0 Fixed menu false positive on click for
7ced47ade57a1d677288e7c98a20eaf374fc2efe final (hopefully) ie fix for menu js
66af4165df70640c6f65cf1ba58db48f2d89012d v0.5
f2954f57eaf2b8a9261680d2d34fd4022178b539 Final menu style, added sidebar styling
04432e237098cccd464a17b7a50226d55b7b4c48 ie fix for previous commit
476e33937a9f6bc8383cd04d8cfe967e25090bc0 Fixed menu false positive on click for
```

I suspect I've been doing something wrong or have otherwise misunderstood my situation.

Comment: What does `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` show? That does indeed look odd, as 1) you're not using `git log --all ...`, so you should only be seeing one branch, and 2) even if that's more than one branch, making otherwise identical commits on two different branches should give different SHA-1s due to the differing parentage.

Comment: Well, I don't really know what to say; I just tried it again after running `gitk --all` and trying `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` and now everything looks as expected (viz. not duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

This is not duplicated, it is simply showing you the same commits in other branches.
try runing `gitk --all` it will give you the real graphic representation of your repo and you will see where the commits really are.

Comment: I've actually been working solo on this project and haven't (intentionally, anyway) branched this repo. Whatever the case, things seem to have resolved themselves, though I don't rightly know how.